# Illegal conversion: can not convert from "byte[]" to "java.math.BigDecimal" ERRORCODE=-4474, SQLSTATE=null

Tags: java, hibernate, javafx, db2

Tengo la siguiente consulta:

```
SELECT datoUno(double), datoDos(double), datoTres(varchar) 
FROM
    Table_ejemplo
WHERE
    dato_ID IN (164246, 164353,...);
```

Mi problema viene cuando desde mi clase implementadora para los parámetros de dato_ID le paso un List como este: [164246, 164353, 123131,...].

Este es el código:

```
private TransaccionResponse busquedaEjemplo(List<Integer> lstEjemplo) {
        StringBuffer sql = new StringBuffer();

        creaQueryEjemplo(sql);

        SQLQuery query = db.createSQLQuery(sql.toString());

        query.addScalar("datoUno", StandardBasicTypes.DOUBLE);
        query.addScalar("datoDos", StandardBasicTypes.DOUBLE);
        query.addScalar("datoTres", StandardBasicTypes.STRING);

        query.setResultTransformer(
                Transformers.aliasToBean(BeanReporteEjemplo.class));

        query.setParameter("datoId",lstEjemplo);

        List<BeanReporteEjemplo> resultados = query.list();

        BeanReporteEjemplo= new ArrayList<BeanReporteEjemplo>();

        for (Object object : resultados) {
            BeanReporteEjemplo b = (BeanReporteEjemplo) object;
            BeanReporteEjemplo.add(b);
        }

        return new SimpleTransaccionResponse(BeanReporteEjemplo);
    }
```

**BeanReporteEjemplo**

```
private double datoUno;
private double datoDos;
private String datoTres;

    public final static Campo PROP_DATO_UNO = new Campo("datoUno",
            "dato Uno", double.class, 150, false, null,
            new RendererSimple(Renderer.CENTER));
    public final static Campo PROP_DATO_DOS = new Campo(
            "datoDos", "dato Dos", double.class, 150, false,
            null, new RendererSimple(Renderer.CENTER));
    public final static Campo PROP_DATO_TRES = new Campo("datoTres", "dato Tres",
            String.class, 150, false, null,
            new RendererSimple(RendererSimple.CENTER));



 public static List<Campo> getCampos() {
        List<Campo> campos = new ArrayList<Campo>();


        campos.add(PROP_DATO_UNO);
        campos.add(PROP_DATO_DOS);
        campos.add(PROP_DATO_TRES);

        return campos;
    }



 getters() and Setters()....
```

Me arroja es siguiente error:

> 2019-11-01 09:53:06,642 WARN  :  SqlExceptionHelper - SQL Error: -4474, SQLState: null
>   2019-11-01 09:53:06,642 ERROR :  SqlExceptionHelper - [jcc][1083][10406][3.66.46] Illegal conversion: can not convert from "byte[]" to "java.math.BigDecimal" ERRORCODE=-4474, SQLSTATE=null

El problema se presenta cuando paso un List: [164246, 164353, 123131,...] pero cuando, realizo una sub-consulta en lugar de pasarle el list,lo realiza sin problema.

De esta forma no me genera ningún error.

```
SELECT datoUno(double), datoDos(double), datoTres(varchar) 
FROM
    Table_ejemplo
WHERE
    dato_ID IN (SELECT
    DISTINCT dato
FROM
    tableExample
WHERE
    datoEjemplo = 1142
    AND datoEjemplo = 1);
```

Les agradecería si alguien pudiera orientarme para resolver esta situación.

Comment: Estás pasando un dato del tipo `byte[]` a otro objeto donde el dato fue declarado del tipo `BigDecimal`. Debes revisar que sean del mismo tipo. ¿En qué línea ocurre el error?

Comment: Me arroja el error en la linea **List<BeanReporteEjemplo> resultados = query.list();**

Comment: ¿Podrías agregar a la pregunta la clase `BeanReporteEjemplo`?

Comment: @A.Cedano ya he agregado la clase.

Comment: Lo que se percibe es que quieres crear una lista de objetos del tipo `BeanReporteEjemplo`, pero en esa clase no veo más que un método `getCampos()` ¿Podrías decir exactamente qué es lo que quieres hacer aquí: `List<BeanReporteEjemplo> resultados = query.list();`

Comment: Es correcto, quiero que la lista de resultados del query ejecutado se guarde en la lista del tipo BeanReporteEjemplo. Esto ya lo he logrado, he editado la pregunta para una mejor explicación.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

La solución de generar una sub-consulta en lugar de pasarle el list me fue funcional hasta cierto punto, debido a que no en todos los casos puedo generar las sub-consultas.

Al final me di cuenta de un detalle muy básico la verdad. Pues estaba pasando un lista de datos como si fuera un solo parámetro, de esta forma:

```
query.setParameter("datoId",lstEjemplo);
```

La forma correcta de realizarlo es la siguiente:

```
query.setParameterList("datoId",lstEjemplo)
```